# How to change VARCHAR type to DATETIME using ALTER in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, sql-update, varchar, alter-table

How can I change `VARCHAR()` type to `DATETIME` using `ALTER` in MySQL?

Comment: Do you have existing data in your varchar column that you want to convert into datetime?

Comment: Does you table column has data already ?

Comment: @beny23, Pranav: what should I do If there is some data exist in table.

Comment: @beny23 Yes.  It's an ISO8601 formatted date/time string.  Will MySQL convert it correctly?

Answer (score 25):

```
ALTER TABLE <tblName> MODIFY <columnName> dataType constraint;
```

For your requirement it will be

```
ALTER TABLE <tblName> MODIFY <columnName> datetime;
```

Refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Answer (score 2):

Try this query.

```
ALTER TABLE  `table_name` CHANGE  `From Date`  `From Date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

Comment: Zero dates are not valid in mysql 5.7+. Default to either `NULL` or `"1970-01-01 00:00:01"` (unix epoch, first valid date in strict mode). Other options are `DEFAULT NOW()` or `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` depending on need. Note that `DEFAULT NOW()` is not legacy compatible.

Answer (score -1):

Why not you just use

**`STR_TO_DATE(str,format)`** ,

It takes a string str and a format string format and returns a **DATETIME** value if the format string contains both date and time parts.

Reffer this [LINK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) , Hope it may help you

Comment: Not what the OP was asking for.