# Mysql select users which have birthday current month

Tags: mysql

I have stored in the database in a varchar column the birthdays like this

dd/mm/YYYY

How can I select the birthday people from the current month directly from MySQL query??

And show using PHP

Thanks

Comment: Can you change the DB? Or you can't do it, and now you are looking for solution?

Comment: [This link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) has everything you need. Please spend sometime on these materials before you proceed

Comment: check my answer might help you  ...!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    yourtable
WHERE
    MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(yourdatefield, '%d/%m/%Y')) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Comment: `NOW()` is a function, not a constant.

Comment: but it's still the best answer

Comment: @jaczes, it indeed answers the *current* question. But *best* is debatable.

Comment: @PauloJoséOliveiraRosa Maybe, it didn't work because of my typo with brackets? Let me know about your table structure. Must work.

Comment: the data is stored in varchar colmun in this format dd/mm/YYYY

Comment: @PauloJoséOliveiraRosa What result did you get from mysql? I can't give you more until I see the database structure.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: check my answer might help you

Comment: @TusharGupta It will give the same result as my request

Comment: U have the best answer tyvm i got this working using this SELECT * FROM jos_gerencia_clientes where date_format(str_to_date(aniversario, '%d/%m/%Y'),'%d/%m/%Y') = MONTH(NOW())

Comment: date_format(str_to_date(DOB, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%m') will give the month

Comment: go it sorry my mistake

Answer (score 10):

First, **do not** store dates as a `VARCHAR`. [Convert it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335880/how-to-change-varchar-type-to-datetime-using-alter-in-mysql) to a `DATE`.

Once that's fixed, use one of the many [MySQL date time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MONTH(birthday) = MONTH(NOW());
```

Comment: any help on converting?

Comment: Check the link or do a Google search. But you'll want to add a new `date` column, migrate the `varchar` to a `date`, then remove the old `varchar` column. Rename the new `date` column if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming date is stored in `%m/%d/%Y` this format you can change this format according to your need.

and `%m` we are selecting only the month and comparing it to the current month `MONTH(NOW())`.

Replace `DOB` by your column and `table` by your table name

```
select * from table
  where date_format(str_to_date(DOB, '%m/%d/%Y'), '%m') = MONTH(NOW());;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change your column type to `DATE`. e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE `people` CHANGE  `dob` `dob` DATE NOT NULL;
```

By doing so you can then use the MySQL query date functions to filter the results.

```
SELECT * FROM people WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(dob) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

Comment: the year part is only neccessary when you want someone born in a specific year and month, not just month

Comment: @Garytje I interpreted the "current month" as the month we are currently in (meaning this year)

Answer (score 1):

```
For Get User list whose birthday in current month in mysql if field datatype is date 
        $Toaday = '%'.date('-m-').'%';

        $query = " select * from client where birth_date LIKE '$Toaday' ";

    In your case declare $Today = '%'.date('/m/').'%';
```

Answer (score 0):

As you used a **VARCHAR** field instead a **DATE** field,

you have to cast the value and then use the normal date functions. like

```
SELECT * 
   FROM table_name 
   WHERE MONTH(CAST(col_name AS DATE)) = MONTH(NOW());
```

Answer (score 0):

I have store dates as a timestamp in tables so I create a query like this. and it's working fine.

**don't use varchar for a date.**

```
select first_name, last_name, date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(`dateofbirth`), '%m/%d/%Y') as dob from users where date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(`dateofbirth`), '%m') = MONTH(NOW())
```