# How to convert text datatype to datetime in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In mysql database,column name created.This "created " column is text datatype,I need to change this to datetime.Now this column  have so many datas.Is it possible to convert it or?

Database look like

```
created
18-11-15 18:21:25
```

Expecting ouput is

```
created
2018-11-15 18:21:25
```

When am doing

```
ALTER TABLE invoices MODIFY created datetime
```

This query giving wrong data.its converting from 15-09-18 03:03:43 to 2015-09-18 03:03:43

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378003/convert-varchar-column-to-date-in-mysql-at-database-level

Comment: but sir i need to convert it into datetime not date

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335880/how-to-change-varchar-type-to-datetime-using-alter-in-mysql

Comment: @TeeKea when am doing "ALTER TABLE invoices MODIFY created datetime" This converting from 15-09-18 03:03:43 to 2015-09-18 03:03:43

Comment: I just want like 2018-09-15 03:03:43

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the original data is not in [MySQL Datetime](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) format (**YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**), you cannot just change the column datatype from Varchar/Text to Date/Datetime. Otherwise, there will be an irreparable Data loss.

This will be a multi-step process. You will first need to convert the date string to [MySQL date format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html) (**YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS**). We can use [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function for this.

Your sample date string (`18-11-15 18:21:25`) is basically in `%y-%m-%d %T` format. Following format specifiers can be used:

- `%d`     Day of the month as a numeric value (01 to 31)
- `%m`     Month name as a numeric value (00 to 12)
- `%y`     Year as a numeric, 2-digit value
- `%T`     Time in 24 hour format (hh:mm:ss)

The query to update the date would look as follows:

```
UPDATE invoices  
SET created = STR_TO_DATE(created, '%y-%m-%d %T');
```

Now, you can use [`Alter Table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) to change the data type from Text type to Datetime.

```
ALTER TABLE invoices 
MODIFY COLUMN created datetime;
```

Comment: how to convert 04-10-18 13:17:23 to 2018-10-04 13:17:23????it mean some datas are in the format of dd-mm-yy.so i need to convert it first.How to update these datas?

Comment: when am doing UPDATE invoices SET created = STR_TO_DATE(created, '%y-%m-%d %T') WHERE invoiceID BETWEEN 2031 AND 2520; showing error #1411 - Incorrect datetime value: '2004-10-18 13:17:23' for function str_to_date

Comment: before updating i need to change my data from 04-10-18 13:17:23 to 2018-10-04 13:17:23

Comment: @becool how come you have two different formats in the same column ?

Comment: later i was changed my code to yyyy-dd-mm. before i was saving dd-mm-yy as text datatype.Becoz  mysql date format accepts only yyyy-mm-dd.So that i changed

Comment: Is there any way to interchange 04-10-18 13:17:23 to 2018-10-04 13:17:23 invoiceID BETWEEN 1834 AND 2031

Comment: @becool problem here is that how would you know 04-10-18 is 4 October 2018, or it is 18 October 2004 ?

Comment: am confirmed that 2018-10-04.2018 only i have created database.There is no datas in 2004

Comment: @becool can you set up a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ with sample data covering both cases. I will need to do some testing, before giivng a final answer

Comment: sir u want data or query?

Comment: @becool click on Load Example button in the top menu bar. You will get the idea. Basically in the left side you add create table and insert into table statements to generate the example case (with sample data) and then click on save. It will generate a link. share the link with me.

Comment: first three data format like dd-mm-yy and 4,5,6 are yy-mm-dd format..All data i need to convert like 2018-09-15 18:51:41 where id=1 and example two is like 2018-10-04 21:24:01 where id=4

Comment: @becool check the update query in this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x2TAfgVjC88c173cSXboMp/1

Comment: sir sorry for the delay.Yeah its working now.Thanks a lot :)

Comment: hi sir i need your help.i posted new question can u plz help me to do this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382219/how-to-count-all-values-of-columns-where-two-conditions-are-satisfied-using-mysq

Comment: When am downloading to excel sheet , I am getting $row['exclvat'] is 20.00 but excel sheet showing 20.If $row['exclvat'] is 80.98 then excel sheet showing 80.98.Only if 0.00 not showing.how can i change this in php code without manual changes in excel sheet?

Comment: Hi @becool, I am unable to follow what you are asking for. It is always good to post a new question and share the link, I will try to answer (if question has enough details).

Comment: sir already i have shared link.here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53382219/how-to-count-all-values-of-columns-where-two-conditions-are-satisfied-using-mysq

Comment: Can u  able to check my new post?Can u reply to that post,i will explain it clearly

Answer (score 0):

The *best* thing to do here is to not store your dates as text.  Assuming you have already done this, we can cope by calling `STR_TO_DATE` to generate a bona fide date:

```
SELECT
    STR_TO_DATE(created, '%y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS created_out
FROM yourTable;
```

Since the output you expect is standard date output, we can stop here and avoid also calling `DATE_FORMAT` to generate a different output.

Comment: sir i dont want select  query.I just want to alter my datatype and change in column data also without removing data

Comment: _Don't_ do this!  Store proper dates instead!

Comment: when am doing ALTER TABLE invoices MODIFY created datetime. This converting from 15-09-18 03:03:43 to 2015-09-18 03:03:43

Comment: Then create a new datetime column and populate it using the output of `STR_TO_DATE` above.  Then, delete your original text date column.

Comment: then how about the values in created column(text datatype)?This will be lost?

Comment: You may retain the original text date column if you wish.  It is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

you want to convert output or database records ? for second you can use sql query :

UPDATE 'table_name' SET 'created' = CONCAT('20', 'created')

Comment: What happens if the year be 1988?  Then your solution would generate 2088.

Comment: @Skeldar I just want to convert my database records and datatype also

Comment: i got limited data but  its super rare that he got "created" dates before 2k its possible but i will say ok my solution is kinda holes.

Answer (score 0):

You will need first to interchange the *day* with the *year* in the **created** column, as follows:

```
UPDATE invoices
SET created = CONCAT(SUBSTR(created, 7, 2), '-', SUBSTR(created, 4, 2), '-', SUBSTR(created, 1, 2));
```

Then, you convert the column to DATETIME, as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE invoices MODIFY created DATETIME;
```

Hope this helps.