# How to count all values of columns where two conditions are satisfied using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables one is "invoices" and other is "invoice_items".so i want to generate report using these two tables.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @Kurohige updated sir.plz check my question again

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick...please have a look on CASE WHEN

```
select i.Date, i.No,sum(CASE WHEN t.VAT<>'no'  THEN 
amount ELSE 0 END) as  Excluding_VAT,
sum(t.amt_vat)as vatamount,
sum(CASE WHEN t.VAT='no' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as  NonVat,
sum(t.amt_vat+t.amount)as totamt
from a i join b t on i.ID=t.ID
where i.Date between '1991-11-18' and '1995-11-19'
group by i.ID,i.No,i.Date
```

Comment: @becool have a look on number_format (https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp) php function

Comment: @becool I tried <td>".number_format($row['exclvat'],2)."</td> and worked fine on LibreOffice...

Comment: @becool that is excel/libreoffice calc's auto formatting feature. It is not concerned with PHP or MySQL code. You will have to turn off some setting in there.

Comment: @becool check this: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/stop-automatically-changing-numbers-to-dates-452bd2db-cc96-47d1-81e4-72cec11c4ed8

Comment: @becool this is an example to stop auto formatting. You really need to google this. It is not a new problem.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya how can i leave non vatable field blank instead of showing zero (sum(CASE WHEN t.includeVAT='no' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) as Non_Vatable)

Comment: @becool simply handle these data display related requirements in your php code. Keep query simple as much as you can

Answer (score 0):

this is for **Sale_Value_Excluding_VAT**

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM (select amount from invoice_items join invoices on invoices.invoiceid=invoice_items.invoiceid
where includevat=TRUE) AS T
```